# Solving the integral without using Laplace

Tags: definite-integrals

On my last question, i was trying to find the Laplace of the following function,
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-2t}\sinh t\sin t }{t} dt.$$
Now I am wondering, can I solve the integral directly without using the Laplace, could someone provide me some hints to solve the integral, I am having some trouble where to start from.
Well, I am thinking of writing the $\sinh{t}$ and $\sin{t}$ in their exponential form or is there any other way to solve this question?

Comment: So are you saying we mustn't evaluate $\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-st}\sin t}{t}dt$, or just that we mustn't use any knowledge from the theory of Laplace transforms to do it? It's [typically evaluated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Other_problems_to_solve) with the Leibniz integral rule.

Comment: @J.G. we must not use the theory of Laplace transforms to do it, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following integral:

\begin{equation}
I \,=\displaystyle{\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}} \frac{e^{-2t}\sinh(t)\sin(t)}{t}\,dt
\end{equation}

We can simplify the integrand if we transform $\sinh(t)$ into its exponential form, given that:

\begin{equation}
\sinh(t)= \frac{1-e^{-2t}}{2e^{-t}}
\end{equation}

So, our integrand now has the following form

\begin{equation}
I \,=\displaystyle{\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}} \frac{e^{-2t}\sin(t)(1-e^{-2t})}{2te^{-t}}\,dt \,\,=\displaystyle{\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}} \frac{\sin(t) - e^{-2t}\sin(t)}{2te^{t}}\,dt
\end{equation}

Now, separating the integrand leaves us with two *very similar* integrals to compute:

\begin{equation}
I\,=\displaystyle{\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}} \frac{\sin(t) - e^{-2t}\sin(t)}{2te^{t}}\,dt \,\,= \displaystyle{\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}} \frac{e^{-t}\sin(t)}{2t}\,dt \,\,- \displaystyle{\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}} \frac{e^{-3t}\sin(t)}{2t}\,dt
\end{equation}

Let's consider the following integral:

\begin{equation}
I(\alpha)\,=\displaystyle{\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}} \frac{e^{-\alpha t}\sin(t)}{2t}\,dt \,\,\,\,\,\,\forall \alpha>0
\end{equation}

It is clear that we can express our original integral $I$ in terms of $I(\alpha)$, such that:

\begin{equation}
I = I(\alpha = 1) - I(\alpha = 3)
\end{equation}

We can compute $I(\alpha)$ using the Leibniz rule, or what it is sometimes called differentiation under the integral sign. Now, let's differentiate $I(\alpha)$ with respect to $\alpha$:

\begin{equation}
\frac{dI(\alpha)}{d\alpha} = \frac{d}{d\alpha}\left[\displaystyle{\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}} \frac{e^{-\alpha t}\sin(t)}{2t}\,dt\right]
\end{equation}

Given that the upper and lower bounds are not dependent in our parameter $\alpha$, by the Leibniz rule, we can introduce the ordinary derivative into the integrand, transforming it into a parcial derivative with respect to our new parameter:

\begin{equation}
I'(\alpha) = \displaystyle{\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}} \frac{\partial}{\partial\alpha}\left[\frac{e^{-\alpha t}\sin(t)}{2t}\right]\,dt = \displaystyle{\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}} \frac{e^{-\alpha t}\sin(t)(-t)}{2t}\,\, dt = -\frac{1}{2}\displaystyle{\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}} e^{-\alpha t}\sin(t)\,\, dt
\end{equation}

The last integral is fairly easy to integrate, as it can be solved integrating by parts twice. This cyclical integral yields the following expression:

\begin{equation}
\displaystyle{\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}} e^{-\alpha t}\sin(t)\,\, dt = \frac{1}{1 + \alpha^{2}}
\end{equation}

So, we now have a new expression for $I(\alpha)$:

\begin{equation}
I'(\alpha) = -\frac{1}{2\left(1 + \alpha^{2}\right)}
\end{equation}

Now, we would like to integrate $I'(\alpha)$ with respect to $\alpha$, in order to go back to our original expression. To do so, we need to find appropiate integration limits. We would like to find a limit in which our integrand goes to zero, and another one that allows us to go back to our initial integral. Notice that the integrand vanishes when $\alpha \rightarrow +\infty$, given that the definite integral of zero over any inteval, must be zero, then $I(\alpha \rightarrow +\infty)=0$, so we will let our upper bound approach infinity. We can let our lower bound be $\alpha$.

Let's integrate both sides of the equation with respect to $\alpha$, in the interval $(\alpha, \infty)$:

\begin{equation}
\displaystyle{\int\limits_{\alpha}^{+\infty}} I'(\alpha) = \underbrace{I(\alpha \rightarrow +\infty)}_{zero} - I(\alpha) = -\frac{1}{2}\displaystyle{\int\limits_{\alpha}^{+\infty}} \frac{d\alpha}{1 + \alpha^{2}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
I(\alpha) = \frac{1}{2}\displaystyle{\int\limits_{\alpha}^{+\infty}} \frac{d\alpha}{1 + \alpha^{2}} = \frac{1}{2}\Big[\arctan(\alpha \rightarrow +\infty) - \arctan(\alpha)\Big]  
\end{equation}

Finally, we obtain an expression for $I(\alpha)$:

\begin{equation}
I(\alpha) = \frac{1}{2}\bigg[\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan(\alpha)\bigg]
\end{equation}

We can further simplify the last expression if we consider the following identity:

\begin{equation}
\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\alpha}\right) = \frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan(\alpha) = \mathrm{arccot}(\alpha) \,\,\,\,\, \forall \alpha>0
\end{equation}

So, our initial integral $I(\alpha)$ can be expressed as follows:

\begin{equation}
I(\alpha)\,=\displaystyle{\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}} \frac{e^{-\alpha t}\sin(t)}{2t}\,dt = \frac{1}{2}\mathrm{arccot(\alpha)}
\end{equation}

With this result, we can finally compute our original integral $I$:

\begin{equation}
I = I(\alpha = 1) - I(\alpha = 3) = \frac{1}{2}\bigg[\mathrm{arccot(1)} - \mathrm{arccot(3)}\bigg]
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
I \,=\displaystyle{\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}} \frac{e^{-2t}\sinh(t)\sin(t)}{t}\,dt = \frac{\pi}{8} - \frac{1}{2}\mathrm{arccot(3)} \approx 0,231823\,...
\end{equation}

[The result given by Wolfram-Alpha](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezqU1.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Apply Frullani integral theorem twice (see Wikipedia).  The OP's integral can be written as
$$I=\frac{1}{2}\Big( \frac{1}{2i}\int_0^\infty \big( e^{-t(1-i)} - e^{-t(1+i)}\big) \frac{dt}{t} -\frac{1}{2i}\int_0^\infty \big( e^{-t(3-i)} - e^{-t(3+i)}\big) \frac{dt}{t}\Big)$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\Big(  \frac{1}{2i} \log{\big((1+i)/(1-i)\big)} -  \frac{1}{2i} \log{\big((3+i)/(3-i)\big)} \Big)$$
$$= \frac{1}{2}\big( \frac{\pi}{4} - \frac{1}{2} \tan^{-1}(3/4) \big) $$